# Restore AdminParty state on CouchBase Single Server?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

I'm using a local machine for development that needs to allow Admin Party (everyone is an admin). When I first installed CouchBase Single Server, it was working, but I created a user and that turned Admin Party off. I've re-installed multiple times. Killed off everything I can find associated with couchbase, but every re-install retains the Admin Party off configuration, and remnants of my old database(s).

For reference:

- Host: OS X 10.7.2
- CouchBase Single Server Binary (not installed from source)
- CouchBase SS Version: 1.2

I've tried blowing away the following:

```
    /Applications/Couchbase\ Single\ Server.app/*
    ~/Library/Application\ Support/CouchbaseServer/*
```

but things must still be being stored elsewhere. lsof doesn't yield anything except for files in those locations and this:

```
    /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Fixed this on my own. After more find/grepping for [Cc]ouch, i found the following files:

```
/Users/redacted/Library/Caches/com.couchbase.couchbase-server
/Users/redacted/Library/Caches/com.couchbase.couchbase-server/Cache.db
/Users/redacted/Library/Logs/Couchbase.log
/Users/redacted/Library/Logs/Couchbase.log.old
/Users/redacted/Library/Preferences/com.couchbase.couchbase-server.plist
/Users/redacted/Library/Preferences/com.couchbase.couchbase-server.plist.lockfile
/Users/redacted/Library/Preferences/couchbase-server.ini
/usr/local/Library/Formula/couchdb-lucene.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/couchdb.rb
```

Because I'm re-installing couch anyway, there is no reason for me to keep anything couch related. I blew all of these away, reinstalled and Admin Party was re-enabled. Somehow it still has record of my old DB names, but at least admin part is back in action.

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me answer my own question, but I solved it on my own:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution other than re-installing the server:

Remove (or move) `~/Library/Preferences/couchbase-server.ini`

Then, finally, my Admin Party came back!

Answer (score 2):

Search inside your CouchDB configuration files (`local.ini`, `default.ini`, `local.d/*`, ... usually under `/etc/couchdb` or similar) for the `[admins]` section and comment out all the users defined there (use `;` character).

Restart your CouchDB server and you'll be back in Admin Party mode.

Comment: You also need to set `require_valid_user` to `false` (or just comment) in `[couch_http_auth]` section if you have that set to `true`.